# SQL - Get per column count of differences when comparing two tables

Tags: sql, teradata

I have 2 similar tables as shown below with minor difference between some cells

#### Table A

| Roll_ID | FirstName | LastName | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | XXX | 31 |
| 2 | BBB | YYY | 32 |
| 3 | CCC | ZZZ | 33 |

#### Table B

| Roll_ID | FirstName | LastName | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | XXX | 35 |
| 2 | PPP | YYY | 36 |
| 3 | QQQ | WWW | 37 |

*I would like to get an output that shows the count of different records on a per-column level.*

For example the output of the query for the above scenario should be

### Output

| Roll_ID | FirstName | LastName | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

For this question we can assume that there will always be one column which will have non-null unique values (or one column which may be primary key). In above example Roll_ID is such a column.

**My question is:** What would be the *most efficient way to get such an output*? Is there anything to keep in mind when *running such query for tables that may have millions of records* from point of view of efficiency?

Comment: Looks like you just need an inner join but if you need a count on `roll_id` then perhaps it does need a full join. Use expressions like `count(case when A.FirstName <> B.FirstName then 1 end)`. If nulls are involved then the comparisons get harder.

Comment: You tagged the question with 4 different rdbms products. Which one do you actually use? You also need to define how exactly you want to perform the comparisons. For example, what's the expected count if in table B the fist name is CCC for Roll_ID 2. CCC as first name is present in table A, but for a different roll id. Also, how do you handle situations, when you have roll id 4 in table A only and roll id 5 in table B only (all other roll ids match). What will be your count for roll id 1 or 2?

Comment: @shawnt00 an inner join will always give you a count of 0 for the join column(s)y, so count for roll id would not be necessary.

Comment: @Shadow, I have edited to specify Teradata or any standard ANSI solution would be perfect. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Shadow, That's was pretty much my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to join the tables

```
   SELECT *
   FROM table1
   JOIN table2 on table1.ROLL_ID = table2.ROLL_ID
```

Now just add the counts

```
   SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN table1.FirstName <> table2.FirstName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FirstNameDiff,
      SUM(CASE WHEN table1.LastName <> table2.LastName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LastNameDiff,
      SUM(CASE WHEN table1.Age <> table2.Age THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AgeDiff
   FROM table1
   JOIN table2 on table1.ROLL_ID = table2.ROLL_ID
```

If an id not existing in both tables is considered "different" then you would need something like this

```
   SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(table1.FirstName,'x') <> COALESCE(table2.FirstName,'y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FirstNameDiff,
      SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(table1.LastName,'x') <> COALESCE(table2.LastName,'y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LastNameDiff,
      SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(table1.Age,-1) <> COALESCE(table2.Age,-2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AgeDiff
   FROM ( SELECT table1.Roll_id FROM table1 
          UNION
          SELECT table2.Roll_id FROM table2  
   ) base
   LEFT JOIN table1 on table1.ROLL_ID = base.ROLL_ID
   LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.ROLL_ID = base.ROLL_ID
```

Here we get all the roll_ids and then left join back to the tables.  This is much better than a cross join if the roll_id column is indexed.

Comment: Your 2nd query will not work as expected unless you switch to LEFT JOINs (but a simple  FULL JOIN is better)

Comment: @dnoeth -- yes you are right -- I thought left join in my head and even put in the COALESCE statements -- but forgot to change that code it seems.

Comment: Also you want UNION DISTINCT in this case (or just UNION, which defaults to DISTINCT), not UNION ALL which retains duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(ISNULL(A.FirstName, '') <> ISNULL(B.FirstName, ''), 1, 0)) AS FirstNameRecordDiff,
       SUM(IIF(ISNULL(A.LastName, '') <> ISNULL(B.LastName, ''), 1, 0)) AS LastNameRecordDiff,
       SUM(IIF(ISNULL(A.Age, 0) <> ISNULL(B.Age, 0), 1, 0)) AS LastNameRecordDiff
FROM A
    FULL OUTER JOIN B
        ON B.Roll_ID = A.Roll_ID;
```

This query intentionally allows nulls to equal, assuming that a lack of data would mean the same thing to the end user.

As written, it would only work on SQL Server. To use it for MySQL or Oracle, the query would vary.

Comment: This solution accounts for situations where table A and B have a different number of rows ... for example, if A has rows with IDs 1, 2, & 3 and B has rows with 1, 3 & 5.

Comment: This only works on SQL Server IIF is not an SQL standard

Comment: True. If on MySQL, the OP would need to use IF() instead of IIF(). Shame he didn't put in a tag targeting what engine he's using.

Comment: @Paurian. I’ve edited tags to add Teradata. However any standard ANSI solution would be great.